# Left sided margin in beamer

Tags: beamer, spacing, margins

I'd like to ask you how the main text "(i) X'' weakly..." would be placed slightly more right side? 
I hope that the sentences (i) and (ii) start right below "The ..." in conjecture.
Maybe it's easier to set margin, but I've no idea for this because conjecture should not be affected.

I would be happy if you someone helps me!

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Beamer does things differently than standard LaTeX, so this will require a lot of trial and error.  A Minimal Working Example would be useful.

Comment: What command would be useful?

Comment: A MWE (Minimal Working Example) is the code used to generate the above document.  OTOH, you might try using the enumerate environment.  It adds a little space to the left, pauses between items, and aligns the left side of the text to the right of the label.  One can customize using `\labelwidth`, `\labelsep` and `\theenumi`.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!